# Finding records for users who re-visited within 30 days across historical data

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a MySQL query that will return all rows for when a person `VisitorID`  returned within 30 days `DateOfService`. Ideally, I would like for the query to return all fields, but the sample has the relevant fields to make the query work.

### Sample of the Table

```
VisitorID DateOfService Cost   TransactionID
001       2008-08-15    150.00 11-235-24 
001       2008-09-07    175.00 11-272-50
002       2008-08-15    155.00 11-688-14 
002       2008-09-16    181.00 11-841-67
001       2011-01-07    190.00 12-851-41
001       2011-01-18    100.00 12-901-55
003       2011-02-05    150.00 12-951-14
003       2011-02-15    180.00 12-998-51
```

### Ideal query results

```
VisitorID DateOfService Cost   TransactionID
001       2008-09-07    175.00 11-272-50
001       2011-01-18    100.00 12-901-55
003       2011-02-15    180.00 12-998-51
```

I've tried variations using group by, but I can't seem to get it to do it in a rolling 30 day window.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1 
INNER JOIN table t2 
  ON t1.VisitorID = t2.VisitorID AND
     t1.TransactionID != t2.TransactionID AND
     t1.DateOfService > t2.DateOfService AND 
     datediff(t1.DateOfService, t2.DateOfService) < 30
```

[demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/470f6/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery in order to get the difference in days between current  / previous records:

```
SELECT `VisitorID`, `DateOfService`, `Cost`, `TransactionID`
FROM (
  SELECT `VisitorID`, `DateOfService`, `Cost`, `TransactionID`,
         DATEDIFF (`DateOfService`,       
         (SELECT `DateOfService`
          FROM mytable AS t2
          WHERE t1.`VisitorID` = t2.`VisitorID` AND 
                t1.`DateOfService` > t2.`DateOfService`
          ORDER BY t2.`DateOfService` DESC 
          LIMIT 1)) AS daysDiff
  FROM mytable AS t1) AS t
WHERE daysDiff <= 30
```

The outer query simply filters out rows having a difference that is greater than 30 days.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0dc41/2)